# textbox ip validation does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a textbox intended to receive an IP address, and I want it to be validated before submission. To achieve this, I've created a separate JavaScript class called validityCheck

and in my main component(Vue.js) I want to use this class to validate the input if its in a right IP format

it does not do anything actually,how can i use the validation here?

here is the validity check class(js class):

```
const validations = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$';

function validationInput(input) {
  if (validations.test(input)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
export default validationInput;
```

here is the main component:

```
<TextBox :label="$t('ChangeServerIpAddress')" v- 
model="ipAddress" @input="validationInput" />
<p v-if="false">IP address is not valid</p>
```

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but you can replace `if (validations.test(input)) { return false; } return true; }` with `return !validations.test(input);`.

Comment: `validations` is a string. Strings don't have a `test` method. Did you mean to create a regular expression? A regular expression literal has slashes `/` instead of quotes `'`.

Comment: @jabaa yes exactly,i meant regular expression ,its not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes `'` are used for string literals. Strings don't have a `test` method. You should see an error in your console:

```js
const validations = '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$';

function validationInput(input) {
  return validations.test(input);
}

console.log(validationInput('127.0.0.1'));
```

You want a regular expression literal with slashes instead of quotes.

```js
const validations = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;

function validationInput(input) {
  return validations.test(input);
}

console.log(validationInput('127.0.0.1'));
```